# How to retrieve mysql data based on cell click event.

Tags: php, html

I have a table which has user names. When I click a user I need to retrieve their information from mysql database and this information will be populated into the relevent textboxes. I am totally stumped on how I go about doing this? Can someone please help

Comment: first do some pesonal efforts and a google research, start something and when you have a specific issue we can help you.

Comment: I have tried  but I am totally stumped!

Comment: I can tell it in another way ... the answer strongly depends on the question ... so if you don't have a quality in the question - you won't have a quality in the answer. Make a good question on a specific task and most of the people here will try to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the jquery code which will solve your issue.  Write this code in a javascript function.  onclick event of that button should call this function.  Write all your db coding in yourpage.php.

```
url = "yourpage.php";

    $.get
    (
        url,
        {
            'act'       :'getdata'
        },
        function(responseText)
        {           
            strData = responseText;

            $('#div_id').html(strData);

        },
        "html"
    );
```

Place all your html code inside DIV and call the div in jquery code.  It will work.

Comment: thanks I'l mark it as answer since your adamant it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery to achieve this in ajaxed way. In test.php write your php mysql code.

The below code a javascript code used to get data from a different page where you can process and get the information about any particular user. Read about ajax.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.php',
      data: 'id=<?php echo $id?>',
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(data) {
         //you can get data as an array and parse it to get fields and you can put them whever you want.
                 $('.result').html(data);
         alert('Load was performed.');
      }
});
```